# Issue with click event in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is probably going to be something really simple. But I am having hard time figuring out what is wrong with how my react component is written. Here is the component code.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import styles from './Menu.css';
import SubMenu from './SubMenu';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

let cx = classNames.bind(styles);

export default class Menu extends Component{
static propTypes ={
  menuData:PropTypes.array.isRequired
};


constructor(props){
super(props);
 this.state = {menuOpenedLabel:""};
};
menuClick(label){
  this.state.menuOpenedLabel = label;
};

render(){
  let menus = this.props.menuData.map(function(menuItem){
  let handleClick = this.menuClick.bind(this,menuItem.label);
  return (<li key={menuItem.label}>
    <a onClick={handleClick}>{menuItem.label}</a>
    <SubMenu subMenu={menuItem.submenu} isVisible={this.state.menuOpenedLabel === menuItem.label}/>
  </li>);
  });

return (<nav>
  <ul className={styles.menu}>{(menus)}</ul>
</nav>);
 }
}
```

This is the error that I get in chrome.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menuClick' of undefined
```

At first I thought it was because of using `this` inside of the map function, but apparently that this code is correct. Based on this link.

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/expose-component-functions.html

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try binding menuClick in the constructor?

Comment: The only time you should be doing this.state = something is in your constructor in es6. Instead what you should in your menuClick function is doing this.setState({ menuOpenedLabel: label})

Comment: if I change the this.state = label to this.setState({menuOpenedLabel:label}); I get this now Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Menu component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out! there is a second parameter to map(), that controls what the value of this is.

```
let menus = this.props.menuData.map(function(menuItem){
  let handleClick = this.menuClick.bind(this,menuItem.label);
  return (<li key={menuItem.label}>
    <a onClick={handleClick}>{menuItem.label}</a>
    <SubMenu subMenu={menuItem.submenu} isVisible={this.state.menuOpenedLabel === menuItem.label}/>
  </li>);
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component is fine, but map stuff can be confusing to look at sometimes. I find this a useful chunk of code, maybe it will help you even though you already figured it out:) Just a way of organizing a map and you get the index, too.

```
render() {
    const { stuffs } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      {stuffs.map((stuff, i) => {
          return(
               <Components key={i} funStuff={stuff.fun} />
          );
      })}
      </div>
    )
}
```